# Bishul akum for canned vegetable soup

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food, bishul-akum, yoreh-deah

According to Halacha, the general requirement for Bishul akum would be if the food is eaten cooked instead of raw, and is fit to be eaten at a king’s table.

Would vegetable soup, which is eaten cooked, be considered something that is subject to bishul akum (since say when it’s pre cooked and you merely heat it up when you want to eat it).

Comment: Probably depends on the particular item. I see no reason to expect a general rule for all vegetable soups

Comment: Generally we assume the White House kitchen would not open a can of prepared soup for a state dinner -- they would prepare it fresh -- so no. That's the prevailing heter behind the OU, Star-K, and the like. (The various hechsherim have asked White House and royal kitchens about things liked canned cranberry sauce, or baked beans.) The Chazon Ish felt it was "anything a king would be willing to eat", even at his private breakfast table, which is much broader.

Comment: (It would therefore include canned sardines, which George V ate for breakfast daily, or baked beans, which the King of Norway would eat on a hunting trip. Most of us don't follow this Chazon Ish.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R Moishe Dovid Lebovits answers your question ([here](https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol14Issue6.pdf), p. 17)

> **A soup which contains food that is edible raw is obviously not subject
> to bishul akum** (such as broccoli, fruit or mushroom soup). It would
> seem that **even a food which is not edible raw that is pureed in a soup
> would not be subject to bishul akum since the main ingredient is water**
> (similar to beer and coffee).
>
> If the product is visible in the soup and it is a food which is fit to
> be placed on a king’s table, then the soup would require bishul
> Yisrael (such as real chicken soup, potato or rice soup).
>
> But certain soups are not fit to be served on a king’s table and there
> is no bishul akum concern for those soups (such as lentil soup or
> split pea soup).